# How to create a final job within ADO CI pipeline yaml that will only run once all the parallel jobs within a loop of tests and devices finish?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, xcode-ui-testing

Suppose, I have ADO CI pipeline with UI tests, and suppose thepipeline iterates through a list of devices and tests which can change between pipeline runs like so:

```
 - ${{ each device in parameters.devices }}:
      - job: RunUITests_${{ device.uniqueName }}
        timeoutInMinutes: 240
        variables:
        - name: iosDevice
          value: ${{ device.deviceType }}
        dependsOn: BuildUITests
        displayName: 'Run UI Tests - ${{ device.deviceType }} -'
        strategy:
          matrix:
            ${{ each testSuite in parameters.testSuites }}:
              ${{ testSuite }}:
                testSuite: ${{ testSuite }}
          maxParallel: ${{ parameters.parallelTestSuites }}
        steps:
        - checkout: self
          fetchDepth: 1
    
        - script: |
           ...
    
        - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
          displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
          inputs:
            artifactName: 'BuildTestProducts'
    
       
        - task: CmdLine@2
          ...
    
        - task: CmdLine@2
          ...
    
        - task: Xcode@5
          displayName: 'Run UI Tests'
          ...
          useXcpretty: true
            xcprettyArgs: '-r junit --output "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(iosDevice)-$(testSuite)-out.xml"'
    
    
        - more tasks...
        ...
```

These UI tests can and do get parallelized between different agents. One of the jobs will write errors to temp file.

How can I add a final job that will only run once the entire loop `- ${{ each device in parameters.devices }}:` with **all** its nested jobs and tasks gets finished (such that I could send the complete error file to a python script)?

I could normally add `dependsOn:` property to the final job, but `dependsOn` requires a name that it depends on, and a loop such as `- ${{ each device in parameters.devices }}:` doesn't have a static name, and the list of devices and tests can change. Naturally, the jobs within the loop also cannot be depended on to mark a final job because there is no guarantee which of the nested jobs will finish first.

**UPD**: updated code to include more details

I basically want to do something with the output of the `Xcode5` task, so I need my python script to run once after the entire loop is done. I have it working already, but the script gets launched multiple times for each iteration, which is suboptimal. I want to make it better this way.

Comment: What do you mean "nested jobs"? There's no such thing. You're on the right track with building your `dependsOn` in a loop based on the contents of the `devices` list. Whatever's in the list will be set as a dependency, no matter how the list evolves over time.

Comment: By `nested jobs/tasks` I mean the jobs/tasks that are part of the loop (indented to the right from the loop declaration). So, I would create that final job at the same indentation as the loop, correct? How exactly would I write out the `dependsOn:` for that final job in this case? Would it be `dependsOn: RunUITests_${{ each device in parameters.devices }}:`? ChatGPT told me that's illegal and then lists don't resolve dynamically like that for `dependsOn:` in ADO.

Comment: `dependsOn: - ${{ each device in parameters.devices }}: - RunUITests_${{ device.uniqueName }}`. It's hard to show without being able to demonstrate proper indentation, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: @DanielMann could you please give proper indentation in a code block? If it works, I'll award you the answer. I updated the code to include more details. I basically want to do something with the output of the Xcode task, so I need my python script to run once after the entire loop is done. I have it working already, but the script gets launched multiple times for each iteration, which is suboptimal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick without having to alter anything in the first job's definition:

```
# Final job
- job: finalJob
  dependsOn:
    - ${{ each device in parameters.devices }}:
      - RunUITests_${{ device.uniqueName }}
  condition: always()
  steps:
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine this with matrix strategy:

```yaml
parameters:
  devices: []

jobs:
- job: test
  strategy:
    matrix:
      ${{ each device in parameters.devices }}:
    maxParallel: ${{length(parameters.devices)}}
  steps:
  - script: echo ${{ device.uniqueName }} 

- job: 'Publish'
  dependsOn: 'Test'
```

As far as I know there is not other way as dependsOn here must be known at compile time.